# icacls viewing permissions relative to the root of a folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions

If I have two folders:
`C:\windows\system32\tasks\` and `C:\temp\tasks\` and I want to compare permissions on them.

I can use the `icacls "C:\temp\tasks\*" /T > C:\temp\tasks_temp.txt` to compare them, but it always results in absolute paths.

Is there a way to make the output of the command display files and folders relative to the directory the command was run in?

Comment: How about `icacls "C:\temp\tasks\*" /save "C:\temp\tasks_temp.txt" /T`? Otherwise you could simply delete the absolute paths (in this case `C:\windows\system32` and `C:\temp`) from each file before comparing.

Comment: Doesn't that output binary?

Comment: Not binary, something like this: `Filename.ext
D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4129710790-1670214157-1866183465-1000)` If you don't want that then the other suggestion above is probably your only way out.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that this is not the output that I'm getting...oh wait, when I open it in notepad instead of VIM it looks fine.  hmm must be some weird encoding.

Comment: Unicode little endian without BOM.

Comment: Ecch!  I guess Vim doesn't detect that.