# Opening a "Unicode little endian without BOM" file from the command line with WinMerge?

Tags: windows, command-line, encoding, winmerge

I have a pair of ["Unicode little endian without BOM"](https://superuser.com/questions/902499/icacls-viewing-permissions-relative-to-the-root-of-a-folder?noredirect=1#comment1210536_902499) text files that I would like to diff each another via the command line.  Unfortunately when I open them using the commandline in Winmerge they come up as a bunch of unreadable binary symbols because the encoding WinMerge is expecting is wrong.

Is there any way to feed these into Winmerge in a readable format?

Comment: How about saving them with a different encoding using Notepad or Notepad++ or other text editor first?

Comment: It's actually the format that it comes out as from `icscls`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was the one who told you about icacls /save yesterday on your last question, remember? :) Just asking why you can't convert before feeding the files to WinMerge?